# Magento2 pagination disable - lazy load

Tags: category, pagination, lazyload

I have a Porto theme in default Magento2 installation. Is there an easy way to disable pagination on category page (where products are displayed). I would like to completely remove pagination and use lazy load. Is this hard to acchieve? Will I need a custom module for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggested some free extensions for lazy load:

- https://www.weltpixel.com/magento-2-lazy-load-product-extension.html
- https://www.magetop.com/magento-2-infinite-scroll-extension.html
- https://magepow.com/magento-2-infinite-scroll-extension.html
- https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-infinite-scroll.html

Hope one of the above extension helps you..!!